# Multiple cross-domain resources end-point in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, cors, angularjs-resource

Here is my scenario:

I am going to build a AngularJS webapp which requires to interact with multiple **cross-domain** server. There are two approaches:

1. **Make all the requests from client side** - From my understanding AngularJS enable us to build a rich client and make REST call to server to obtain data. However for this approach I have to handle CORS issue.
2. **Moving those call to server side (Node.js)** - Node.js makes all the calls to cross-domain server. It exposes REST API for AngularJS to request Node.js to make those calls.

Which approach is suitable for my scenario? Are there any criteria that can guide me to use which approach?

Those cross-domain resources are not maintained by me. I have no way to control their ways to provide resources. Also at least one of the resources does not support CORS. At this moment I config a proxy to handle those call.

Comment: Cross domain issues come when the request is considered complex. Basically you can make cross domain call for GET operation without a problem.

Comment: Those cross-domain resources are RESTful and not maintained by me. I have to use other http action.

Comment: HTTP actions other than GET do not make sense if you just want to get data.

Comment: Most likely they are RESTful resource. I have modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to interacting with cross domain, you options are using either CORS or JSONP if supported by target server.
In case not the only viable option is to proxy the request through your own server.

You can make everything proxy through your server but that would require effort and time to implement.
I don't see any harm in doing the normal CORS or JSONP way for server that support it and use the proxy approach when the underlying infrastructure does not support it.

Comment: Is it a common practise in **AngularJS** to make all the calls from client. My mind set is still stick to the traditional server-client model (Approach 2).

Comment: You are creating a type of mashup. Proxying data through your server also has a performance penalty. Option 1 is also a client server model, except the server is not your server :)